# Replace some text with a picture

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to replace a text (wherever it finds a TEXT, it should be replaced with an image) with an image in the *JasperReports* report. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

I searched over the internet but couldn't find anything so please don't rate me negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this task with help of *printWhenExpression* attribute.

### The sample

#### Datasoure

I've used the *csv* datasource (*holidays.csv*):

```
name,date
New Year's Day,January 1st
Christmas Day,December 25th
Valentine's Day,February 14th
```

#### The report's design

I've placed two *textFields* for showing holiday's name and the holiday's date. And I've placed the *image* element for showing image under the *textField* with holidays name.

With help of *printWhenExpression* I'm showing the holiday's name or image.

The report's design in *iReport*:

[image]

#### The report's template

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="holidays" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e0310045-780b-4af3-aa7b-ed7f5da1985f">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="66" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="RealHeight">
                <reportElement uuid="e7738ed8-673e-49e9-8c14-060378cb6a79" x="0" y="0" width="263" height="66">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}.equals("Christmas Day")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["mc.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="167148f8-ad51-4c87-9faa-27bf18f2160e" x="0" y="0" width="263" height="66" forecolor="#FF6666">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$F{name}.equals("Christmas Day")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Forte" size="24" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ad7c75b4-975b-478e-8a44-090a63c52896" x="263" y="0" width="263" height="66"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="24" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

#### The generated output

And the generated report will be (via preview in *iReport*):
[image]

---

***Notes***

You can complicate the image's expression and use, for example variable for getting image name (or name with path).

Comment: if i need to put the path of a pic than what kind of address should i put in [CDATA]??

Comment: Example, for Windows: `<imageExpression><![CDATA["D:\\path\\mc.jpg"]]></imageExpression>`

Comment: what if i want the address to be in respect to the jasper file?

Comment: i mean if the name of the file is to be fetched from an element than what should i do. This is not working:

<imageExpression><![CDATA["D:\\path\\$F{id}.jpg"]]></imageExpression>

Comment: also tell me how would the above need to be changed if the CSV data-source would have had "this is Christmas Day" but we need to show the result as "this is *christmas pic*".

Comment: Look at my [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20776381/876298). It is contains answers on your new questions