# Replace some text with a picture: how to draw the image instead of word in sentence

Tags: jasper-reports

#### Datasoure

I've used the *csv* datasource (*holidays.csv*):

```
name,date
New Year's Day,January 1st
Christmas Day,December 25th
Valentine's Day,February 14th
```

#### The report's design

I've placed two *textFields* for showing holiday's name and the holiday's date. And I've placed the *image* element for showing image under the *textField* with holidays name.

With help of *printWhenExpression* I'm showing the holiday's name or image.

The report's design in *iReport*:

[image]

#### The report's template

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="holidays" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e0310045-780b-4af3-aa7b-ed7f5da1985f">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="66" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="RealHeight">
                <reportElement uuid="e7738ed8-673e-49e9-8c14-060378cb6a79" x="0" y="0" width="263" height="66">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}.equals("Christmas Day")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["mc.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="167148f8-ad51-4c87-9faa-27bf18f2160e" x="0" y="0" width="263" height="66" forecolor="#FF6666">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$F{name}.equals("Christmas Day")]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Forte" size="24" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ad7c75b4-975b-478e-8a44-090a63c52896" x="263" y="0" width="263" height="66"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="24" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

#### The generated output

And the generated report will be (via preview in *iReport*):
[image]

---

what can i do in the report to get a result like this(the datasource is also changed to this is an christmas day):

[image]

Comment: You can place textField and image together

Comment: I've added another solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The first solution: the image behind the textField element

#### Datasoure

I've used the *csv* datasource (*log.csv*):

```
level,message,image
DEBUG,Some debug message. We are starting,
INFO,Some info. Parameter1 value: 20,info.jpg
WARN,Some warning message. Something going wrong: value is not set,warning.jpg
ERROR,Some error message. The error occurs: file is corrupted,
FATAL,Some fatal message. The disk is full. OutOfMemoryError take place,
```

#### The report's design

I've placed two *textFields* for showing message level and the message. And I've placed the *image* element for showing image under the *textField* with message level's icon.

With help of *printWhenExpression* I'm showing the message level's icon or text. I'm showing the icon if it is defined in datasource (field *image*) or the text (the field *level*) if not defined.

The *imageExpression* is:

```xml
<imageExpression><![CDATA["d:\\path_to_icons\\" + $F{image}]]></imageExpression>
```

We can set the full path to the image (the path plus file name from the datasource).

The report's design in *iReport*:

[image]

#### The report's template

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="log_sample" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a3c5b928-7218-48e8-9de5-7c9f328d3420">
    <import value="com.google.common.base.Strings"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="level" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="message" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="image" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="RetainShape">
                <reportElement x="61" y="0" width="61" height="20" uuid="cefb0c61-75f7-4b8c-a92c-72bc728ddb0b">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!Strings.isNullOrEmpty($F{image})]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["d:\\path_to_icons\\" + $F{image}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="61" height="20" uuid="2fb8ab6c-9253-4a8d-80ac-08a7c963f13e"/>
                <textElement markup="none"/>
                <text><![CDATA[The level is:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="61" y="0" width="61" height="20" uuid="9795b7ef-a38c-43d3-8867-f5cd85b602cc">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Strings.isNullOrEmpty($F{image})]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{level}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="122" y="0" width="433" height="20" uuid="841e0cfa-1ca5-4e6b-8e12-d5f2ff65a2e2"/>
                <textElement markup="styled"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["The message is: <i>" + $F{message} + "</i>"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

#### The generated output

And the generated report will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]

### The second solution: using Html element

#### Datasoure

I've used the *csv* datasource (*text2replace.csv*):

```
text
This is a row with IMAGE
This is an another row IMAGE at the middle of the sentence
Another row. Just a text
```

#### The report's design

I've used the *Html* element.

With help of *hc:htmlContentExpression* attribute I've set the html code: I replaced the occurrences of string *"IMAGE"* with html tag `<img>` for drawing images.

The *hc:htmlContentExpression* is:

```xml
<hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA["<div style='font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; height: 20px;'>" + $F{text}.replaceAll("IMAGE", "<img style='width: 20px; height: 20px;' src='file:///e:/path_to_file/image.jpg' alt='image'/>") + "</div>"]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
```

The report's design in *iReport*:

[image]

#### The report's template

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="replace_text" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5e2b75e0-8b53-41b0-b90a-f36d1022c233">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="text" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" uuid="06badd57-cfad-4909-b390-5a0747f4a297"/>
                <hc:html xmlns:hc="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/htmlcomponent http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/htmlcomponent.xsd" scaleType="RetainShape" horizontalAlign="Left" verticalAlign="Middle">
                    <hc:htmlContentExpression><![CDATA["<div style='font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; height: 20px;'>" + $F{text}.replaceAll("IMAGE", "<img style='width: 20px; height: 20px;' src='file:///e:/path_to_file/image.jpg' alt='image'/>") + "</div>"]]></hc:htmlContentExpression>
                </hc:html>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

#### The generated output

And the generated report will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]

---

***Notes***

- I've used the method [com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty(String)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) from [Google's Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained) for checking if the image set or not. It is import string `<import value="com.google.common.base.Strings"/>` in my *jrxml* file.
- The another sample is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20759705/876298)

Comment: And what do you want? :)

Comment: taking the above example, what should i do if i want to replace the "message" word from the message column to be replaced by the image.

Comment: i have a column in database whose values are like:<br/>
1. this is a |IMAGE|<br/>
2. this is another |IMAGE|<br/>
3. this is third |IMAGE|<br/>
i want to replace the |IMAGE| by a real image which is stored in my pc. I know how to get the image from pc but i'm stuck with the replacement thing.

Comment: In other words you want to replace any word in sentence to image, am I right?

Comment: can't i use <imageExpression> in <textField> tag?

Comment: You can try to replace word *IMAGE* with html tag `<img>` for report in *html* format (*JRHtmlExporter*). Or you can try to generate a report dynamically with *JasperReports API* or *DynamicJasper API*

Comment: `can't i use <imageExpression> in <textField> tag?` - No

Comment: I've added another solution

Comment: i tried iText for pdf generation and it is a lot much better than iReport.